# Jetty - blocked http requests for short period of time (up to 12 seconds)

Tags: java, ajax, servlets, ubuntu, jetty

I am using Jetty 7.3.1 as my webContainer on ubuntu server. I have there heavy loaded web, 300 users online, with a lot of ajax. My problem is, that every 1-2 minutes jetty stops to accept http requests, and those requests are waiting, mostly up to 12 seconds and than are processed.  How can I find out what is going on???  Can I track logs somehow? How do I find that jetty is not restarting in that 12 seconds. Maybe there is something very wrong configured and jetty is trying to restart to fix it. How can I find out what is going on? Thanks for any idea.

I have enough of memory and CPU load is fine.

Here is my config snipet from jetty.xml:

```
<Set name="ThreadPool">       
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool"> 
        <Set name="minThreads">50</Set> 
        <Set name="maxThreads">600</Set> 
        <Set name="detailedDump">false</Set> 
      </New> 
    </Set> 


    <Call name="addConnector"> 
      <Arg> 
          <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector"> 
            <Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.host" /></Set> 
            <Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.port" default="80"/></Set> 
            <Set name="maxIdleTime">30000</Set> 
            <Set name="Acceptors">2</Set> 
            <Set name="statsOn">false</Set> 
            <Set name="confidentialPort">8443</Set> 
            <Set name="lowResourcesConnections">5000</Set> 
            <Set name="lowResourcesMaxIdleTime">2000</Set> 
            <Set name="useDirectBuffers">false</Set> 
          </New> 
      </Arg> 
    </Call>
```

Comment: I found solution. The lags were cause by JRebel. I kicked Jrebel out, and all lags are gone. Bad Bad JRebel:(

Answer (score 0):

If you send the process a QUIT signal ("kill -SIGQUIT PID"), it will make a stack dump of all threads to stdout. Perhaps it will give you an indication on what the server is actually doing.

Comment: I forgot to notice, that I started to use JRebel. I did jstack, and one of many threads is calling some JRebel functions, so maybe Jrebel could cause that lags.

Answer (score 0):

You may have enough memory, but that doesn't mean it's being used and released efficiently. My first suspect would be a "stop the world" garbage collection, or CMS failure, occurring. You may want to profile garbage collection.

The second suspect would be some sort of a synchronization issue, where multiple threads all pile up waiting for the same resource. Again, profiling may help you find this. This may be what you are seeing in JRebel.

Comment: It is not problem of garbage collection for sure. I have this project for years, and those lags are new. I just did some changes, and something is worng. Changes were: I added JRebel, Jetty is loaded programatically(before it was loaded externaly), and I added some filters for continuations.  It is 100% not programing problem. I am just missing something. I had many problems with jetty + reverse ajax, like enabled directbuffer, it crashed jetty. But now, I don't know how could i do this profiling. How can I use Jrebel for profiling?

Comment: "It is 100% not programing problem." - I quit paying attention right there.